# RabbitMQ .Net Desktop Applicaiton Running In backgroud task

Tags: .net, multithreading, rabbitmq

i am working on .NET RabbitMQ Client with my dektop applicaiton(**multithreaded each thread has its own channel**). i simply create a **EventingBasicConsumer** and create event for Received method as per docs.
how i create thread.

```
for (int i=0;i< Convert.ToInt32(txtNumOfChannels.Text); i++)
                    {
                       Thread thrd = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Process));
                       thrd.Start("Threadwise-Channel");
                    }
 void Process(object  typeName)
        {
              IModel channel_consume = conn.CreateModel();
                channel_consume = connection.CreateModel();

                channel_consume .QueueBind("abc", "abcexc", "abc", null);
                channel_consume .BasicQos(0, 1, false);
                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                   //do work

                    try
                    {
                        if (channel_consume.IsOpen)
                        {
                            channel_consume.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
                            //write in db
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                };
                tag = channel_consume.BasicConsume("abc", false, consumer);
}

on application exit button
i simply close all connection and channel but I find that my desktop appliction is still running in task manager.
all channel close and conn are closed i confirmed it with management studio.
 on form closing.
```

```
conn.Close();
```

```
it will be a bottle neck issue b/c we have same exe in one differnt that will control with their config file. as per my thinking .net client not able to kill all threads
```

Comment: Add conn.Dispose() as well

Comment: it still running. i already tried this

Comment: Can you also post the section where the threads are being spawned and what are you doing with the threads on Form Closed event.

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee
i have posted

Comment: What about the close event ?

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee already tried